# Trying to write a django query to count different rows and find the max value

Tags: mysql, django

I have a django app that stores documents (photos, pdfs, video, ect.) as well as some metadata (year, decade, etc.). The metadata is stored in a JSONField called `metadata` in a model called `DocumentMetaData`. I would like to create a django query that allows me to find the maximum number of documents for a certain metadata name.

For example, all documents have in their metadata field a "Decade" value. I can loop through all the decades to find the decade with the most documents, like this:

```
decades = ['1860', '1870', '1890', '1900', '1910', '1920', '1930', '1940', '1950', '1960', '1970', '1980', '1990', '2000','2010', '2020']
max_count = 0
max_decade = ""
for decade in decades:
    count = DocumentMetaData.objects.filter(metadata__has_key='Decade').filter(metadata__Decade=decade).count()
    if count > max_count:
        max_count = count
        max_decade = decade
```

Can I replace this code with a django query using `annotate` and `aggregate`? I am just not seeing how to create a query with a loop in it.

Thanks!